# Condition within GROUP_CONCAT()

Tags: mysql, conditional-statements, group-concat

Guys I have the following tables in my DB

**locations**

- id (primary key)
- name

**projects**

- id (primary key)
- location_id (foreign key => locations)
- projectname

**milestones**

- id (primary key)
- name

**statuses**

- id (primary key)
- status

**project_milestones**

- id (primary key)
- project_id (foreign key => projects)
- milestone_id (foreign key => milestones)
- status_id (foreign key => statuses)

Here, For listing all the Milestones (which has status 9) of all projects, I'm using following query

```
SELECT projects.projectname, locations.name, DATE_FORMAT(projects.created_at, '%d-%m-%y') as     projectdate, 
 GROUP_CONCAT(milestones.name ORDER BY project_milestones.milestone_id ASC separator '<br/>')     AS milestones 
FROM projects INNER JOIN locations ON projects.location_id=locations.id 
INNER JOIN project_milestones ON project_milestones.project_id=projects.id  AND     project_milestones.status_id=9 
INNER JOIN milestones ON project_milestones.milestone_id=milestones.id 
INNER JOIN statuses ON project_milestones.status_id=statuses.id 
AND project_milestones.milestone_id=milestones.id GROUP BY  projects.projectname
```

Result looks like this

```
Location    Date Created    Project Name    Milestones (Status 9)
Bangalore   25-10-11        ABCD            CSO Contacts, Developer
Bangalore   11-11-11        Friday          Establish, Publish list
Bangalore   08-11-11        XX              CSO Contacts, Assemble,Layouts
```

It's working great, But what I need is Another GROUP_CONCAT column say **Milestones (Status 10)** to display all the Milestones (which has status 10) of all projects.

Output like all Projects with [Status-9 Milestones] and [Status-10 milestones] listed. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  *,
        (
        SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(m.name ORDER BY m.id)
        FROM    project_milestones pm
        JOIN    milestones m
        ON      m.id = pm.milestone_id
        WHERE   pm.project_id = p.id
                AND pm.status_id = 9
        ) milestone_9,
        (
        SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(m.name ORDER BY m.id)
        FROM    project_milestones pm
        JOIN    milestones m
        ON      m.id = pm.milestone_id
        WHERE   pm.project_id = p.id
                AND pm.status_id = 10
        ) milestone_10
FROM    projects p
JOIN    locations l
ON      l.id = p.location_id
```